# Unable to stack object onto another with face snapping

Tags: snapping

Sorry, don't understand, how to use face snapping. I have read this http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh but unable to see some reasonable behavior. I see object jumping somehow, but with no apparent sense for me.

Proof: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3K_3w8wfr8

Comment: Maybe the Blender 2.76 Manual will be more clear for you. https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html Also if you want to snap your objects (the 2 meshes fro the video) to allign properly to the corners use "incresement" instead of "face".

Comment: Snapping includes combining of TWO objects into one location. This is explicitly covered in section `Snapping`, where we have commands like `Cursor to Center`, where `Cursor` is first object and `Center` is the second. On the contrary, there are no pairs of objects in the section `Transform snapping` and below. We have only ONE object specified, like `Face`. It is not evident, WHAT will be combined with Face? Other Face? or may be vertex to face? Or some other combination? This is obvious, that since feature is underdetermined, it can't work.

Comment: Your proof isn't clear regarding to your desired result. Which of the objects are you trying to snap, where to, and etc. Could you roughly model two "snapped" objects as you understand that and provide a screenshot here ? As to `Transform Snapping` section - you can get some clues from tooltips which appear on mouse hover on menu of the Blender itself